# a binary read error occurred when using read.dta13 on a .dta file

Tags: r, loaddata, readstata13

I am trying to load in a STATA data file using read.dta13 from the readstata13 library. When I use the function read.dta13 on this .dta file I get the following error over and over:

> char: a binary read error occurred.

What does this mean?

Here is the code:

install.packages("readstata13")
install.packages("foreign")

library(readstata13)
library(foreign)

dat <- read.dta13("cfps2018person_201911.dta")

Comment: Hi. Difficult to answer, since we probably can't reproduce your issue. You may want to work through this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18423366/6574038. `foreign::read.dta` was used to read Stata data until version 13 and is very similar. Maybe it helps.

Comment: @ridley's mom: Please put the code what you have tried till now, so we can try and reproduce the same